# Document.ready or run after certain time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, preloader

i have preloader , which hides after document.ready .

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    var el =  document.getElementById('preloader');
    fadeOut(el);
});
```

Sometimes document loads so slowly , because of 1 or 2 big size photos , so i don't need to wait for this photos and need to hide preloader after 5000ms.

How can i do that ? 
Thanks in advance .

Comment: SO isn't an advice forum and questions like these tend to result in a lot of opinion-based answers which can easily go out of date. What have you tried so far? Please, show your work.

Comment: OK , main idea is that i cant imagine ,how to add If statmenent with angular.element(document).ready(function () { ...

Comment: `ready` doesn't wait for images to load

Comment: No the document isn't loading slowly, it's finished loading before images are. `document.ready` is just the DOM finishing being parsed, that doesn't mean the images themselves are loaded, just the tag is there. While `window` is what loads everything. Instead use `window.onload`.

Answer (score 0):

That "document ready" process you're using is simply wrapping jQuery's (now deprecated) `.ready()` method. It does *not* wait for all images to load, it only waits for the DOM to be parsed. The `window.onload` event is the event that only fires after all images have loaded.

Instead, Angular has a directive called [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) to prevent a "flash of unstyled content" (FOUC). The cloak works by putting a class on a top level element, which you can then style to hide part, or all, of the page while you wait for a "ready" state. You can use CSS transitions, rather than the jQuery `.fadeOut()` effect, to do a slow fade out on your preloader once the cloak is removed.